# Tensorflow: get_shape() for use in reshape()

Tags: tensorflow

I have some tensor-flow code that involves some reshaping of tensors:

```
# sigma has shape (15000,20,2)
sigma_shape = sigma.get_shape()

# We want to reshape it to (300000,2)
sigma = tf.reshape(sigma, [-1, sigma_shape[-1]]) # (300000,2)

# Because we have to do this operation
Sigma = matrix_with_upper_values(rho) + tf.matrix_diag(tf.square(sigma))

# Reshape back, Sigma is (300000,2,2), we want it to be (15000,20,2,2)
Sigma = tf.reshape(Sigma, sigma_shape.append(sigma_shape[-1]))
```

This is what I want it to do. However:

- `sigma_shape` is a Tensor-shape object and `sigma_shape[2]` a `Dimension(2)` which could not be used in tf.reshape in this way.
- `sigma_shape`.append(`sigma_shape[-1]`) this would also not work. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `value` of a `Dimension` object. Thus

```
 sigma_shape[-1].value
```

Is an `int` value that you can use in you `tf.reshape` calls